# Mono WebService refuses to return json

Tags: json, web-services, mono

I'm trying to create a web service using Mono 3.0.3.5 that returns json.

But so far I have been unable to get a service to return anything but xml. This appears to have been a matter of much discussion in the past, but even after checking my attempts against numerous resources here and elsewhere, I cannot tell what I'm omitting.

I created an empty ASP.NET solution, to which I added an asmx with codebehind page. As far as I'm aware, decorating the service class name with the ScriptService attribute and the method/function name with ScriptMethod and specifying Json for the ResponseFormat attribute are the only necessary steps in the code.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace MonoJsonTest
{
   [WebService]
   [ScriptService]
   public class GimmeJson : System.Web.Services.WebService
   {
      [WebMethod]
      [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
      public    string  simpleTestString()
      {
         return DateTime.Now.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

(I'm aware of the problems putting dates into json, I just wanted some string that would change with subsequent calls to my service)

Then I added System.Web.Extensions to the References of the project. This is built to .NET version 3.5, so I ensured that I included the 3.5 version of System.Web.Extensions.

Then the httpHandlers of web.config was modified to go through the ScriptHandlerFactory (as outlined on a couple of pages I've found)

http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/04/aspnet-ajax-in-mono.html

http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

A sharp eye might notice there is a difference in the web.config changes specified on the two pages. the "Culture=neutral" attribute is specified -inside- the string for the type attribute on the first page, but as an attribute of the add tag on the second. But I found that when specified the second way, there is an error upon starting the service.

My final web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- should produce json responses -->
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But hitting the service (locally) from the WSDL page or with an ajax query from javascript (using JQuery library) it always returns XML. Inspecting the response headers with both Charles and Firefox debugging tools shows me a response type of text/xml.

After research, it seemed I need to request json from the service when making the call, so I set the contentType, accepts, and dataType parameters of the ajax call to specify json but this made no difference. Strangely, even the request headers show the "Accepts" parameter is still specifying xml after I have explicitly set it in the Ajax call.

Here is the ajax call (note accepts and dataType type is set to json) :

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8080/GimmeJson.asmx/simpleTestString",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{}",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log( "success" ); alert.show("success"); },
error: function(request, type, errorThrown) { console.log( "error" ); }
});
```

Here is the request header generated by that call (Accept is still xml):

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:null
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

This produces an HTTP code of 200, and this response header (note content type is xml):

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:103
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 09 Aug 2012 23:38:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Proxy-Connection:Keep-alive
Server:Mono.WebServer2/0.2.0.0 
UnixX-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
```

One thing I have noticed that I'm not sure is an important point but seems odd. I browsed the System.Web.Extensions dll in Mono and noticed that a ScriptHandlerFactory did not seem to exist within it. Modifying the line in the web.config that adds the factory to specify "FOOScriptHandlerFactory" as the type did NOT produce any errors when starting the service, which would seem to indicate Mono is not reporting unfound types in the web.config. But I do not know enough about that aspect of .Net nor Mono to say that for certain. But as this factory is the lynchpin of the automatic Json serialization, this could be important.

I'm not sure what I'm omitting here. I feel like I haven't configured something on the server side correctly or it would be reporting json for the return type somewhere on the WSDL page.  As you may have guessed I'm still new to online development, so my apologies if I'm overlooking Very Obvious Things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the WebMethod static?

The other point I'd consider is whether the functions on the return could return 3 values instead of just one.